# How can I get my login page to direct to the logged-in user profile using handlebars and javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am in the middle of project week, so far I have been able to direct the signup form to the newly signed up user's profile, but not having the same luck with logging in for existing users.

here's my code that lives in the login.js in my front end files.

```
const login = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    const email = document.querySelector('#input-email').value;
    const password = document.querySelector('#input-password').value;
  
    if (email && password) {
      const response = await fetch('/api/users/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      });  
      if (response.ok) {
        window.location.replace('/profile');
      } else {
        alert('Failed to log in');
      }
    }
  };
  
  document
    .querySelector('.login-form')
    .addEventListener('submit', login);
```

here is my backend userRoutes for login:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userData = await User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } });

    if (!userData) {
      res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: 'Incorrect email or password, please try again' });
      return;
    }

    const validPassword = await userData.checkPassword(req.body.password);

    if (!validPassword) {
      res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: 'Incorrect email or password, please try again' });
      return;
    }

    req.session.save(() => {
      req.session.user_id = userData.id;
      req.session.logged_in = true;
      res.json({ user: userData, message: 'You are now logged in!' });
      
    });

  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: The path on the server must match the path that the front-end is requesting. /api/users/ is different from /login.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.location.replace(`${window.location.origin}/profile`);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond! This still isn't working for me, and it isn't even giving me an error when I am console.log-ing

Comment: I can see that the endpoint you are making request to from the frontend "/api/users/" is different from what you have on the backend "/login"

1- inspect your network tab and see what response you are getting from the server
2- add a console log inside the if condition "response.ok" and see if that prints out on the console

then you'll have a better idea on whats going on

Comment: I changed my backend login code to just be `'/'` and that gave me a bad request 400 error, which at least means it is reading the code and giving me an error, but even with a console.log it is saying the issue is with my fetch request

Comment: could you post screen shot of your console log & network tab here